# GKE cluster fails to create instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Creating a gcloud kubernetes cluster from a script and the cluster is takes forever to create, just ends up failing after 35 minutes.

Command:

```
gcloud container clusters create 148374ed-92b0-4088-9623-c22c5aee3 \
    --num-nodes 3 \
    --enable-autorepair \
    --cluster-version 1.11.2-gke.9 \
    --scopes storage-ro \
    --zone us-central1-a
```

The error are not clear, looks like some kind of buffer overflow internal to gcloud.

> Deploy error: Not all instances running in IGM after 35m6.391174155s. Expect 3.
>
> Current errors: [INTERNAL_ERROR]: Instance 'gke-148374ed-92b0-default-pool-66d3729f-6mw3' creation failed: Code: '-2097338327842179396' - ; Instance 'gke-148374ed-92b0-default-pool-66d3729f-qwpd' creation failed: Code: '-2097338327842179396' - ; .

Any ideas for debugging this?

Comment: Go to the Console and now try to resize the cluster larger. You might be hitting a resource problem where a new instance cannot be created due to lack of resources.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem on GKE. Tried different regions, projects and node sizes, nothing worked, same error... The issue started two hours ago

Comment: I have all kinds of issues. Unable to scale, add pools, or even open a Cloud Shell. I've tried 2 regions, no luck. This is causing production issues for us at this point, started over 90 minutes ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been facing similar issue while creating a cluster for the past 3 hours. A ticket has already been raised and GCP engineering team is working on the fix.

For status updates on the ticket, visit https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/18012